# Despliegue jenkins excluyendo archivos

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

Tengo 2 pipelines, una para despliegues generales y otra para archivos de configuración, lo que quiero hacer es que en la segunda pipeline no puedan desplegar ciertos archivos.

Alguna forma de excluir archivos por extensión o rutas.